# How to modify or add resources at runtime in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, resources, runtime, edit

I have an Android app. I used to strings.xml resources for set text in .xml file.

And now, I want to change some text from server side. I know, I can't modify resources at runtime but I think some libraries have solved this problem like [B3nedikt](https://github.com/B3nedikt/restring/blob/master/README.md) or [Hamidness](https://github.com/hamidness/restring/blob/master/README.md). So in 2021, is it possible to modify or add resources at runtime in Android?